# access html 5 camera flash

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, camera

I want to acces phones camera flash(flashlight) automatic.
like this app : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_Lr3d9giCo

We can access camera with this html 5 controller

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

But how can we access camera's flash(flashlight)?is there any html(5) or javascript(jquery or other framework) plugin for this?
I want to acces camera's flash with browser technologies(html 5,javascript,css)

Answer (score 2):

no, There is no attribute in HTML5 to access flashlight.

if you are using Cordova/phonegap/Ionic to package your HTML app you can use the following plugin to access the flashlight

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-flashlight

installation and usage guide is given in above link.

Answer (score 0):

for camera >> take photo

```
<input type="file" id="user" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

for camera >> take video

```
<input type="file" id="environment" capture="environment" accept="video/*">
```